# Change inherit field to required in a Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a serializer like that:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    field2 = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    field3 = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    ...
```

I want to inherit this class but changing `field1`to `required=True`, who can I do that?

I know that I can redefine the field like this:

```py
class MySerializer2(MySerializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField(required=True)
```

But I dont like to do this.

Comment: why do you not want to do what you suggested?

Comment: @shivankgtm My fields has other params too, like `help_text`, `default`, and others, and I dont wanna to redefine it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way I found to solve this until now is to change the field property on the Serializer `__init__`:

```py
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    field2 = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    field3 = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    ...

    def __init__(self, instance=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(instance=instance, data=data, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(self,'update_fields'):
            to_update= self.update_fields
            for field in to_update:
                for attr, value in to_update[field].items():
                    setattr(self.fields[field], attr, value)
```

Now I just need to set the `update_fields` attribute with the fields and properties I want to modify,

```py
class MySerializer2(MySerializer):
    update_fields = {
        'field1': {'required':True},
        'field2': {'help_text': 'New help text'},
    }
```